# how can you test this web layer in junit?

Tags: java, spring, junit

how can you test this web layer in junit ?

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
    Map<String, Object> context = Maps.newHashMap();
    context.put("detail", "hello!");
    return  templateRender.render(getTemplate("index.html"), context);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using REST docs.  You test and document your web API in one shot.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html5/

Comment: What technology do you use? What is the `templateRender` object's type?

Answer (score 1):

Just know, this is no longer unit testing but integration testing which is by definition is a phase in software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group. In this case, you test the integration between the layers - the controller and the service one.

Here you have not many choices to do. You can either:

1. **Trust** that the method `render(..)` does the job well and is already tested by its provider. I'd rather focus on the `getTemplate(..)` method whether it returns a correct template.
2. Use a **front-end** automatized test to call the URL and detect a returned webpage according to given parameters. Selenium or Robot framework is capable to do so. Smoke and sanity tests cover this up as well and server for this purpose.
3. Use a third-party library as already suggested. However, I see no real benefit aside of increasing the code-coverage metrics (be careful - it might be a false-positive indicator).

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you need to test the web page via JUnit. You can use JWebUnit:

```
@Before
public void prepare() {
    setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/test");
}

@Test
public void testLogin() {
    beginAt("/home");
    clickLink("login");
    assertTitleEquals("Login");
}
```

}

Source:
https://jwebunit.github.io/jwebunit/